# analyzing the complexity of a number in arduino

Tags: math, arduino, complexity-theory, numerical-methods, arduino-ide

I'm working on a project where I'm linking a calculator (ti-84) to an Arduino (Nano) and I want some way of **classifying or quantifying how complex a single number** is (small whole numbers being very simple, irrational numbers being the most complex). I don't need it to be a perfect or even a direct/linear map, but the closer the better. Speed of computation is more important in this case.

I was thinking of just counting the number of digits, but I want 1.333333 to be classified as less complex than 1.245682. Also 12,345 should be less complex than 12,973 but more complex than 12,000.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you representing this number? Standard floating point arithmetic only represents a subset of rational numbers, approximations to irrational numbers are detectable in this subset.

Answer (score 1):

One could define the complexity of a number by how much it can be "compressed". This could be via a sufficiently close rational number, where one then counts the total bit length of numerator and denominator. Or in some extension by a close algebraic number with rational coefficients and a rational interval that separates the root in question from all the other roots, again counting the total bit length of all involved integers.

For example the rational approximations of pi 22/7 and 553/311 both barely give more digits in their decimal expansion than they have digits in their integers, giving no compression at all, which makes pi a complicated number.

For a general algorithm to find rational approximations look up "continued fraction expansion". The double precision accuracy should be good for 4 to 6 stages of it, later entries in the integer-parts array will be dominated by errors of the floating point computation. The smaller the numbers in the sequence, and the shorter the sequence of small numbers, the more "simple" the number. A good cut-off to determine such lengths is 20, if the integer parts become larger, the input number is no longer simple.

Another, or extended, approach is to find a "minimal polynomial" via the LLL algorithm, it is a standard example for its use. Again a short coefficient sequence (low degree) and small coefficients make for a more simple number. Note that `x ~ p/q` is an approximate solution to `q*x-p=0`. The pool of simple numbers is here "roots of polynomials of degree 5 or less with coefficients between -20 and 20", or similar.

This should at least give a measure for the small numbers, where the fractional part is more important than the integer part. Larger numbers can be reduced by division by powers or 2 or 10, the resulting measure of complexity should be similar in both variants.

Comment: Looking it up now, it seems like continued fraction expansion for irrational numbers gives an infinite list; if I were to put it into an array capped at say 50 digits, is there a way to know if the list originally had more than 50 digits?

Comment: @LilMamiChula Continued fractions is that they can be used to find [best rational approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations). Then you can say that a number is more complicated if it requires large denominators to approximate closely.

Comment: @LilMamiChula : As I said, the limited amount of mantissa digits gives raise to only a limited amount of reliable fraction steps in the CFE. Also, no floating point number is irrational, so any prolonged expansion is due to floating-point noise, usually detectable when 5-digit numbers appear in the array. As for a feeling of complexity, array elements larger 20 hint at "complicated" numbers, another extreme is the golden ratio and other solutions of quadratic equations that have periodic arrays. These are also "complicated" in the sense of rational approximations.

Answer (score 0):

what format is your input number?

I assume floating point...

First I would print your number to text and then construct `score` based on:

1. number of mantissa digits `O(n)`

   do not forget to account the decadic exponent too (if the number is in scientific format)
2. number of distinct digits used `O(n)`

   so simply do a digit histogram for each decadic didgit `0..9`
3. periodicity `O(n^2)`

   find repeating pattern period if present

where `n` is number of decadic digits (trailing/leading zeros not accounted). 32bit float can store ~7 digits so let n=8 just to be safe.

construct some weight probably in range `(0.0,1.0>` for each of the 3 parameters (zero is not inclusive) and multiply them together you could put more weight on stuff you want to be more significant...

In case you want to also recognize binary to decadic conversion rounding error just multiply the fractional part of number by 10 few times and check if fractional part is not the same as any of the previous multiplication (stop on zero). number of multiplications leading to same subresult is period and if result is zero no rounding occurred.

Comment: Hello Peter, can you join please, need your help https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253702/3d-graphics-ahmed-spektre